# How to 3D-plot with specific ranges?

Tags: plotting, functions

I have the following function which I want to plot using `Plot3D`:

```
(-1 + w + 3 s w)/(2 (-1 + w + 4 s w))
```

, which is only meaningful for the defined ranges:

```
(1/4 < s <= 1/2 && 1/(4 s) < w <= 1) || (s > 1/2 && 
   3/(2 + 8 s) < w <= 1)
```

Is it possible to plot fx like this:

```
Plot3D[(-1 + w + 3 s w)/(2 (-1 + w + 4 s w)), {s, 0, 3}, {w, 0, 1}]
```

using the defined ranges instead of numbers?

Does it even make sense to do so?

The current output with the example above looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have V10? `Plot3D[(-1 + w + 3 s w)/(2 (-1 + w + 4 s w)), {s, w} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[(1/4 < s <= 1/2 && 1/(4 s) < w <= 1) || (s > 1/2 && 
      3/(2 + 8 s) < w <= 1), {s, w}]]`

Comment: I am not familiar with V10.

Comment: `RegionFunction[]` was introduced in v6.0, @Sumit 's answer should work.

Comment: I meant version number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RegionFunction` to specify the range.

```
Plot3D[(-1 + w + 3 s w)/(2 (-1 + w + 4 s w)), {s, 0, 3}, {w, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{s, w, z}, (1/4 < s <= 1/2 && 1/(4 s) < w <= 1)
 || (s > 1/2 && 3/(2 + 8 s) < w <= 1)]]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to do the job. Thx! One question though. Why do you include "z"?

Comment: @Saud, because `RegionFunction` expects a function of three variables, even if you only need two for this example.